# $f_n(x) = x - x^n$ for $x\in [0,1]$. Does the sequence converge pointwise or uniformly on $[0,1]$?

Tags: proof-verification, uniform-convergence

> $f_n(x) = x - x^n$ for $x\in [0,1]$. Does the sequence converge pointwise or uniformly on $[0,1]$?

We also have to prove why it is or isn't pointwise or uniformly convergent.

I have worked out that on $x\in[0,1)$, the limit as $n$ approaches infinity is $x$.
And when $x=1$ the limit is $0$.

So this means its pointwise convergent right? But how do I prove this? 
Also how on earth do I prove it is not uniformly convergent? (I'm just assuming it's not).

Comment: It the convergence were uniform, the limit function would be continuous. But it is not continuous at $1$.

Answer (score 2):

If $0\le x<1$, you have $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=0$. Moreover $f_n(1)=0$. So you have, by basic rules of limits,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
x & \text{if $x\in[0,1)$}\\[4px]
0 & \text{if $x=1$}
\end{cases}
$$
which is pretty much what you did. So the sequence is pointwise convergent.

It is not uniformly convergent, because a uniformly convergent sequence converges also pointwise to a *continuous* function.

Comment: Okay thank you. Do you by any chance know how to prove this?

Comment: ...' because a uniformly convergent sequence of *continuous* functions converges also pointwise to a *continuous* function.'